# Python Generic Data Engine

Tags: python, generics, input, output

I have been working on Python for about 1.5yrs and looking for some direction. This is the first time I can't find what I need after doing a lot of searching and must be missing something- most likely searching the wrong terms.

**Problem**: I am working on an app that has many processes (Could be hundreds or even thousands). Each process may have a unique input and output data format - could be *multiline strings*, *comma separated strings*, *excel* or *csv* with or without varying headers and many others. I need something that will format the input correctly and handle the output based upon the process. New processes also need to be easily added/defined. I am open to whatever is the best approach, but my thoughts are to use a database that stores the template/data definition and use that to know the format given a process. However, I'm struggling to come up with exactly how, if this is really the best approach, but it needs to be a solution that is scalable. Any direction would be appreciated. Thank you.

A couple simple examples of data

**Process 1 example data (multi line string with Header)**
Input of

```py
 [ABC123, XYZ453, CDE987]
```

and the resulting data input below would be created:

```
Barcode
ABC123
XYZ453
CDE987
```

This code below works, but is not reusable for the example 2.

```py
list = [ABC123, XYZ453, CDE987]

input = "Barcode /r/n"

for l in list:
    input = input + l + '/r/n'
```

**Process 2 example input template (comma separated with Header):**

```
Barcode,Location,Param1,Param2
Item1,L1,11,A
Item1,L1,22,B
Item2,L1,33,C
Item2,L2,44,F 
Item3,L2,55,B
Item3,L2,66,P
```

**Process 2 example resulting input data (comma separated with Header):**
Input of

```py
{'Barcode':['ABC123', 'XYZ453', 'CDE987', 'FGH487', 'YTR123'], 'Location':['Shelf1', 'Shelf2']}
```

and using the template to create the input data below:

```
Barcode,Location,Param1,Param2
ABC123,Shelf1,11,A
ABC123,Shelf1,22,B
XYZ453,Shelf1,33,C
XYZ453,Shelf2,44,F 
CDE987,Shelf2,55,B
CDE987,Shelf2,66,P
FGH487,Shelf1,11,A
FGH487,Shelf1,22,B
YTR123,Shelf1,33,C
YTR123,Shelf2,44,F
```

I know how to handle each process with hardcoded loop/dataframe merge, etc. Ive done some abstraction in other cases with dicts. However, how to define/store each format that vary so much and create reusable abstracted code is where I am stuck.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can do the output of the functions as a tuple with the keys "datatype" and "output" for the actual output

Comment: That is essentially what I plan to do, but there is a layer of complexity in defining what the input and output is and how to store those definitions that is my challenge. Ive added some details to clarify a little more.

Comment: I’m giving this an upvote because it inspired a solution I think will work. I’m going to store the templates as json in the dB along with a couple other columns that describe the input. Going to give it a go and see how it works out. Thanks Sven!